# Matlab: How to create a function? In this case my script to a function

Tags: matlab

I want to create an interface between Matlab and c # -> So I have to translate my M-file into a DLL library ".

- I enter "deploytool" in the command window.
- I select "Libary Compiler" A window opens.
- For "Type" I selected .NET assembly

So now my questions comes:
"Add exported functions" -> I have to choose my Matlab function.
But you  can see my m-file is a script not a function. But i need a function..
How  can I Convert it from my script to a function? I mean the code. How is the syntax? I have never worked with functions.
The function should require an input parameter. And the output should be the diagram. But this is implemented (Attachement).

```
diagramoptions = [];
diagramlimits = [];
inputdata = [];

diagramoptions2 = [];
diagramlimits2 = [];
inputdata2 = [];

diagramoptions3 = [];
diagramlimits3 = [];
inputdata3 = [];




wholecontent = fileread('aaaa.txt')
sections = regexp(wholecontent, '\*+([^*]+)\*+([^*]+)', 'tokens')
counter=0; %Sollte mir die Anzahl der Diagramme zurückgeben 
for section = sections
   switch(strtrim(section{1}{1}))
       case 'Diagram Options' %Diagram Options -> siehe meine Gliederung im .txt file
          keyvalues = regexp(section{1}{2}, '([^\n\r=]+)=([^\n\r=]+)', 'tokens')%\n -> new line; \r carriage return
          diagramoptions = cell2table(vertcat(keyvalues{:}), 'VariableNames', {'Key', 'Value'}) 
          counter=counter+1;
       case 'Diagram Limits'
          header = strsplit(regexp(section{1}{2}, '[^\n\r]*', 'match', 'once'))
          content = textscan(section{1}{2}, repmat('%f', 1, numel(header)), 'HeaderLines', 2)
          diagramlimits = table(content{:}, 'VariableNames', header)

       case 'Input Data'
          inputdata = cell2mat(textscan(section{1}{2}, '%f%f%f', 'HeaderLines', 1))
          %output_inputdata(1) = inputdata;

       case 'Cutoff Lines1'
          cuttofflines1 = cell2mat(textscan(section{1}{2}, '%f%f%f', 'HeaderLines', 1))%Cutofflines  


       case 'Diagram Options2' %Diagram Options -> siehe meine Gliederung im .txt file
          keyvalues2 = regexp(section{1}{2}, '([^\n\r=]+)=([^\n\r=]+)', 'tokens')%\n -> new line; \r carriage return
          diagramoptions2 = cell2table(vertcat(keyvalues{:}), 'VariableNames', {'Key', 'Value'})


       case 'Diagram Limits2'
          header2 = strsplit(regexp(section{1}{2}, '[^\n\r]*', 'match', 'once'))
          content2 = textscan(section{1}{2}, repmat('%f', 1, numel(header2)), 'HeaderLines', 2)
          diagramlimits2 = table(content2{:}, 'VariableNames', header2)    

       case 'Input Data2'
          inputdata2 = cell2mat(textscan(section{1}{2}, '%f%f%f', 'HeaderLines', 1))
          %output_inputdata(2) = inputdata;

        case 'Diagram Options3' %Diagram Options -> siehe meine Gliederung im .txt file
          keyvalues3 = regexp(section{1}{2}, '([^\n\r=]+)=([^\n\r=]+)', 'tokens')%\n -> new line; \r carriage return
          diagramoptions3 = cell2table(vertcat(keyvalues{:}), 'VariableNames', {'Key', 'Value'})

       case 'Diagram Limits3'
          header3 = strsplit(regexp(section{1}{2}, '[^\n\r]*', 'match', 'once'))
          content3 = textscan(section{1}{2}, repmat('%f', 1, numel(header3)), 'HeaderLines', 2)
          diagramlimits3 = table(content3{:}, 'VariableNames', header3)


       case 'Input Data3'
          inputdata3 = cell2mat(textscan(section{1}{2}, '%f%f%f', 'HeaderLines', 1))%dh: ich habe 1 Headerline zur besseren übersicht

       case 'Input Data4'
          inputdata = cell2mat(textscan(section{1}{2}, '%f%f%f', 'HeaderLines', 1))
          %output_inputdata(1) = inputdata;   

      otherwise
          warning('Unknown section: %s', section{1}{1})
   end
end
```

My Input txt:

```
*******************Cutoff Lines1****************
-100    100
-200    200
******************* Diagram Options****************
rainflow=1
woehler=0
number_of_plots=4
color=red
linewidth=12
header=Number of cycles
xlabel= RPM
ylabel= Amount
cutoffvalue=53
equivcycles=1e6
equivstress=40
wsectionslope=3 3 3
ordinatelogarithmic=false
wsectionstart=1000 5000000 3000000
wsectionsend=5000000 1000000000 30000000
wsectionlinestyle=cont dashed cont
wsectionstartstress=58.02349610358 58.02349610358 130
******************* Diagram Limits****************
xmin xmax ymin ymax zmin zmax
1   111 1111111 1   1   11
*******************Input Data****************
-220.8  228 50045
-222    201.6   50045
-219.6  19.2    200176
-168    19.2    100088
******************* Diagram Options2****************
number_of_plots=4
wsectionstart=1000 5000000 3000000
******************* Diagram Limits2****************
xmin xmax ymin ymax zmin zmax
0   0   100000  1   1   1100000
*******************Input Data2****************
106.62  1
106.62  50045
18.5181 12260785
******************* Diagram Options3****************
number_of_plots=23655888855665
******************* Diagram Limits3****************
xmin xmax ymin ymax zmin zmax
0   0   100000  1   1   1100000
*******************Input Data4****************
-220.8  228 50045
-222    201.6   50045
-220.2  198 200176
```

Comment: Did you try putting [`function`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) at the top?

Comment: You can have a matlab function without input and/or outputs. Just put `function` on top with the name being matching the file-name.

Comment: Ok i will try. But how looks the syntax if i have a function with one input in my case a .txt-File and an output in my case just a plot window. Or is this not a real output? i am desperate. But anyway thanks